# NSIS: In a custom page how to enable a Dir Request Input if a checkbox is checked

Tags: nsis

I have set the DirRequest inputs flag to Disabled initially, how do i set it to Enabled once a checkbox is checked true in my custom page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the NOTIFY flag:

```
!include InstallOptions.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Page Custom MyPageCreate MyPageLeave
Page Components

Function MyPageCreate
InitPluginsdir
; A real installer would not write the .ini like this, it would extract a file
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" Settings NumFields 2
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 1" Type Checkbox
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 1" Text "They call me the toggler"
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 1" Left 0
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 1" Right 200
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 1" Top 0
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 1" Bottom 14
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 1" Flags NOTIFY
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 2" Type DirRequest
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 2" State "$InstDir"
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 2" Left 0
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 2" Right 200
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 2" Top 20
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 2" Bottom 34
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\mypage.ini" "Field 2" Flags DISABLED
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY "mypage.ini"
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageLeave
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $0 "mypage.ini" "Field 1" "State"
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $1 "mypage.ini" "Field 2" "hWnd"
EnableWindow $1 $0
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $1 "mypage.ini" "Field 2" "hWnd2"
EnableWindow $1 $0

!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $0 "mypage.ini" "Settings" "State"
${If} $0 > 0
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: The number of controls on the page

Comment: Using this the Dir Request input box is getting enabled but the folder selector button next to the input box is not getting enabled

Comment: I had forgotten that the button is really a separate control, fixed now.

Comment: so we are using hwnd2 because its next to the input box?

Comment: hwnd2 is the 2nd control for a few of the "special" controls. DirRequest is not a real Windows control, it is just a normal edit box and a button.

Comment: Now unchecking the checkbox, isbehaving as if im clicking on Next button, due to Notify on field 1 i assume, how to get past that?

Comment: My code works correctly for me. The important part is to call Abort when the setting state has changed.